# Firebase to Bigquery transform function error: invalid json response body

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions, firebase-extensions

I'm trying to implement a transform function for the Firestore to BigQuery Stream extension but I'm getting this error:

> Unhandled error FetchError: invalid json response body at
> https://us-east4-<PROJECT_ID>.cloudfunctions.net/<FUNCTION_NAME>
> reason: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 1

Here is the code:

```
const functions = require('@google-cloud/functions-framework');
functions.http('eventsTransformFunction', (req, res) => {
 
  const inputPayload = req.body;
    const inputData = inputPayload.data[0];
    const outputPayload = [{
        insertId: inputData.insertId,
        json: {
            timestamp: inputData.json.timestamp,
            event_id: inputData.json.event_id,
            document_name: inputData.json.document_name,
            document_id: inputData.json.document_id,
            operation: inputData.json.operation,
            data: JSON.stringify({ createdAt: { _seconds: 1664983515, _nanoseconds: 745000000 }, name: "Transformed Name" })
        },
    }]

    res.send({ data: outputPayload });
});
```

I even tried this and still got the same error:

```
const functions = require('@google-cloud/functions-framework');
functions.http('eventsTransformFunction', (req, res) => {
 
    res.send(req.body).status(200);
});
```

Comment: The inner code of your Cloud Function seems correct at first sight. Did you try to log the value of `outputPayload`? Also can you try writing and running a simple "Hello World" HTTP Cloud Function (not linked to the extension)? Which version of Cloud Functions are you using?

Comment: I tried a simple "Hello World" function and it worked. Also tried to log the input/ouput of the function but no logs are shown because of the error.

Comment: `const functions = require('@google-cloud/functions-framework');
functions.http('eventsTransformFunction', (req, res) => {})` is not a common syntax for Cloud Functions for Firebase (AFAIK). Can you share the **entire** file of your Cloud Functions? And also, can you share your `package.json` file (we need to know the version of Cloud Functions you're using)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't try your code but, at first sight, the inner code of your Cloud Function looks correct. The problem probably comes from the fact that you are not deploying a Cloud Function **for Firebase**.

As a matter of facts

```
const functions = require('@google-cloud/functions-framework'); 
functions.http('eventsTransformFunction', (req, res) => {})
```

is the way for [writing Cloud Functions to be deployed via the Google Cloud Console](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/create-deploy-http-nodejs).

I would suggest to use a Cloud Function **for Firebase**, which has a different syntax and must be deployed through the Firebase CLI. You can follow the [Cloud Functions section of the Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started).

So, for example, by using Cloud Functions 2nd generation, your code should be as follows:

```
const {
  onRequest,
} = require("firebase-functions/v2/https");

exports.eventsTransformFunction = onRequest((req, res) => {
  const inputPayload = req.body;
  const inputData = inputPayload.data[0];
  const outputPayload = [
    {
      insertId: inputData.insertId,
      json: {
        timestamp: inputData.json.timestamp,
        event_id: inputData.json.event_id,
        document_name: inputData.json.document_name,
        document_id: inputData.json.document_id,
        operation: inputData.json.operation,
        data: JSON.stringify({
          createdAt: { _seconds: 1664983515, _nanoseconds: 745000000 },
          name: "Transformed Name",
        }),
      },
    },
  ];

  res.send({ data: outputPayload });
});
```

Comment: You nailed it, thank you